# Searching between beginning and end of today returns empty set

Tags: mysql

This is the failed query:

```
SELECT * FROM court_records 
WHERE county = 1 
AND last_exported_date > '2017-04-21 00:00:00 -0400' AND last_exported_date <= '2017-04-21 23:59:59 -0400';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.12 sec)
```

It says it could not find any records. But then I known there are many records with last_exported_date of today:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM court_records WHERE DATE(last_exported_date) = CURDATE();
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     1609 |
+----------+
```

In fact, here is just one example:

```
SELECT * FROM court_records WHERE id = 43862\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                id: 43862
            county: 1
last_exported_date: 2017-04-21
        created_at: 2017-04-21 16:24:43
        updated_at: 2017-04-21 17:12:58
```

So why does my first query return an empty set? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you store the dates with the timezone difference?

Comment: @aletzo I assume it uses the defaults of mysql

Comment: `last_exported_date` seems to be formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`, so I think that you have to format the dates accordingly in your `where` clause

Comment: My dates are formatted with YYYY-MM-DD in the where clause.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I think that you should remove the `00:00:00 -0400` and `23:59:59 -0400` parts, so in essence your where clause will be `last_exported_date = '2017-04-21'`

Comment: @aletzo while that does fix the issue, why is it an issue? Is there anything I can change in mysql to enable this to match?

Comment: I'm guessing MySQL can't compare `2017-04-22` and `2017-04-21 00:00:00 -0400`, while it can compare `2017-04-22` and `2017-04-21`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
WHERE last_exported_date >= '2017-04-21' AND startTime < ('2017-04-21' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or you can just check the date like this

```
WHERE DATE(last_exported_date)='2017-04-21'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date range is constructed slightly incorrectly.

You have

```
      last_exported_date > '2017-04-21 00:00:00 -0400'  /* off-by-one! */
  AND last_exported_date <= '2017-04-21 23:59:59 -0400';
```

To get the records with dates on 21-Apr-2017, you want this ... notice the change to `>=` and `<`

```
      last_exported_date >= '2017-04-21 00:00:00 -0400'
  AND last_exported_date <  '2017-04-22 00:00:00 -0400';
```

The first expression, the one from your question, happens to exclude any records with a `DATE` value of `2017-04-21` or a `DATETIME` value of `2017-04-21 00:00:00`.

And, it's cleaner, when looking for a whole day's records, to use `< the next day` than `<= the last moment of the current day`.

And, by the way, your timezone indicators do not serve any purpose in MySQL.